# Get multiple categories names from permalink Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, categories, permalinks

I am trying to get categories names for the ones that are available in permalink. e.g. I have the following permalink structure.

`abc.com/product-category/category-1/category-2/`

Where as **category-1** and **category-2** both are categories. When I try `$wp_query->get_queried_object()`, it just returns me info related to **category-2**. How can I get details of *category-1* using any existing wordpress functions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As the previous categories are parent of the current use can get it using get_term https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term/
$child_category = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
$parent_category = get_term($child_category->parent, 'product-category');

Comment: `get_category` is a wrapper for `get_terms` where the `taxonomy` is already set to `categories` so you may only pull the regular post type terms with this I believe, so I imagine products are not inside that taxonomy.

Comment: Ah! Right, I did not see the product category part, get_terms is of course more generic.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the parent of the `category-2` using the `get_term` function.

```php
$child_term = get_queried_object();
$parent_term = get_term($child_term->parent, 'product_cat'); // if your using Woocommerce then the taxonomy is called 'product_cat'
```

Both of these variables will be `WP_Term` objects.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term/

From there you can access the name, id and any other information you need.

**Revised**

If you're wanting to create a custom category page (i.e. not a Woocommerce/WordPress page) then I would recommend adding a `meta-box` to the page editor.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

Have a select box with your product categories.

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/dynamically-populate-a-select-fields-choices/

Then in your page template, use the `term(s) ID` as part of your `WP_Query` to pull products from both of those product categories.

Comment: category-1 & category-2 both are at same level. Its not parent child relationship.

Comment: How have you managed to setup the URL like that? It would suggest parent/child

Comment: basically its like I used that url for filtering. It brings all the products that belong to category-1 and category-2.

Comment: I've revised my answer with a decent solution.

Comment: So there is no core function for wordpress that I can use to get both category names using the permalink?

Comment: I thought the way get_queried_object returns details of category-2 automatically, i could get details of category-1 directly as well?

Comment: If they aren't parent and child then there would be any connection between the two, it's simple just a string in your URL